# Getting specific comments Facebook user downloaded comments.json

Tags: python, json

Facebook allows us to download our own content, and an option is to send it to a json file. I want to parse that file to pull specific comments I've made in a specific Facebook group. I have the comments.json file and have a short snippet of test code that can get the top layers of data. The lowest layer, where the group names and the actual comments are do not parse.

This is on Windows 10 using the IDLE python IDE (python version 3.5.2).

Here is a short sample of the json file -- anonymized:

```
{
  "comments": [
    {
      "timestamp": 1564971950,
      "data": [
        {
          "comment": {
            "timestamp": 1564971950,
            "comment": "Some Text Here",
            "author": "My Name",
            "group": "Group 1 Name"
          }
        }
      ],
      "title": "My Name commented on Other Person's post."
    },
    {
      "timestamp": 1564968688,
      "data": [
        {
          "comment": {
            "timestamp": 1564968688,
            "comment": "Some More Text Here",
            "author": "My Name",
            "group": "Group 2 Name"
          }
        }
      ],
      "title": "My Name replied to their own comment."
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to select on the [comments][data][comment][group]. Here is the
short test python file code I tried:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime

with open('sample.json', 'r') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        for j1 in data["comments"]:
            for j2 in j1["data"]:
                print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(j1['timestamp']))
                ## for j3 in j2['comment']:
                print(j2)
```

Which results in this output

```
2019-08-05 02:25:50
{'comment': {'group': 'Group 1 Name', 'comment': 'Some Text Here', 'author': 'My Name', 'timestamp': 1564971950}}
2019-08-05 01:31:28
{'comment': {'group': 'Group 2 Name', 'comment': 'Some More Text Here', 'author': 'My Name', 'timestamp': 1564968688}}
```

You can see the data is pulled in to j2. When I tried to grab that last level of data, the keys are grabbed, but not the values. The code for this:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime

with open('sample.json', 'r') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        for j1 in data["comments"]:
            for j2 in j1["data"]:
                print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(j1['timestamp']))
                for j3 in j2['comment']:
                    print(j3)
```

And the output:

```
2019-08-05 02:25:50
group
timestamp
comment
author
2019-08-05 01:31:28
group
timestamp
comment
author
```

If I try to grab a specific key (like j3[group]), I get an error - TypeError: string indices must be integers

Which means the json library doesn't recognize this last level as keys and values properly. I can add the square brackets before and after that farthest right set of curly brackets in my sample file and get what I want to get with this code:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime

with open('sample2.json', 'r') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        for j1 in data["comments"]:
            for j2 in j1["data"]:
                for j3 in j2['comment']:
                    if j3['group'] == "Group 1 Name":
                        print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(j3['timestamp']))
                        print(j3['comment'])
```

Which, given I only ask for "Group 1 Name" I get this:

```
2019-08-05 02:25:50
Some Text Here
```

What I'd like to do, since I really don't want to manually edit a 56000 line json file to add all the missing square brackets, is there a way to parse j2 to pull the key/value pairs, as such, from that "comment" set.

```
import json
from datetime import datetime

with open('sample2.json', 'r') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        for j1 in data["comments"]:
            for j2 in j1["data"]:
                for j3 in j2['comment']:
                    if j3['group'] == "Group 1 Name":
                        print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(j3['timestamp']))
                        print(j3['comment'])
```

I expect to pull the data for comments in a specific facebook group from the user downloaded json file and having it output with the timestamp and comment text.

When I try to access that lowest level key/value set I get the error: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the default behavior when iterating over a dictionary by calling it's variable name is calling `dict.keys()`.

It means that this statement:

```
for j3 in j2['comment']:
    print(j3)
```

Actually equivalents to this:

```
for key in j2['comment'].keys():
    print(key)
```

The reason you received *TypeError* is because the action `j3['group']` was called on a string (*dictionary key*) and not a dictionary.

You managed to bypass this exception by changing the value of *comment* key from dictionary to list, so trying to iterate `j2['comment']` actually returned a **list** of one **dictionary**:

```
for dictionary in j2['comment']:
    print(dictionary['your_key'])
```

You can iterate over the key value pairs of j2 **without changing the original JSON file** by doing something like this:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime

with open('sample.json', 'r') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        for j1 in data["comments"]:
            for j2 in j1["data"]:
                for k, v in j2['comment'].items():
                    print('Key: {0}, Value: {1}'.format(k,v))
```

If all you want is to only print comments from a specific group, based on your example, you don't really need to go into another nested loop, e.g:

```
import json
from datetime import datetime

with open('sample.json', 'r') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        for j1 in data["comments"]:
            for j2 in j1["data"]:
                if j2['comment']['group'] == 'Group 1 Name':
                    print(j2['comment']['comment'])
```